# lshw shows a different amount of RAM than the 'free' command. Missing RAM?

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, webserver, ram

uname -a:

```
 Linux servername 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lshw output:

```
  *-firmware
   description: BIOS
   vendor: Dell Computer Corporation
   physical id: 0
   version: A07
   date: 04/25/2008
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 960KiB
   capabilities:
 *-cache:0
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 700
   size: 16KiB
   capacity: 16KiB
   capabilities: internal write-through data
*-cache:1
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: 701
   size: 1MiB
   capacity: 2MiB
   capabilities: internal write-back unified
*-cache:0
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 703
   size: 16KiB
   capacity: 16KiB
   capabilities: internal write-through data
*-cache:1
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: 704
   size: 1MiB
   capacity: 2MiB
   capabilities: internal write-back unified
*-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 1000
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 1GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2.5 ns) [empty]
      physical id: 0
      slot: DIMM1_A
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2.5 ns)
      product: HYMP512R724-E3
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 1
      serial: FFFFFFFF
      slot: DIMM1_B
      size: 1GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
 *-bank:2
      description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2.5 ns) [empty]
      physical id: 2
      slot: DIMM2_A
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
 *-bank:3
      description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2.5 ns) [empty]
      physical id: 3
      slot: DIMM2_B
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
 *-bank:4
      description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2.5 ns) [empty]
      physical id: 4
      slot: DIMM3_A
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
 *-bank:5
      description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2.5 ns) [empty]
      physical id: 5
      slot: DIMM3_B
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
```

Cool, 1 GB of RAM...

free -h output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          244M       194M        50M         0B       256K        12M
-/+ buffers/cache:       181M        62M
Swap:         507M       110M       397M
```

dmesg partial output:

```
[    0.000000] Memory: 237988k/261888k available (3434k kernel code, 448k absent, 23452k reserved, 3305k data, 576k init)
```

cat /proc/meminfo output:

```
MemTotal:         249892 kB
MemFree:            3680 kB
Buffers:             428 kB
Cached:            31796 kB
SwapCached:         9624 kB
Active:           101660 kB
Inactive:         105740 kB
Active(anon):      87668 kB
Inactive(anon):    87888 kB
Active(file):      13992 kB
Inactive(file):    17852 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        520188 kB
SwapFree:         410888 kB
Dirty:             10796 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        172092 kB
Mapped:             8796 kB
Shmem:               288 kB
Slab:              20968 kB
SReclaimable:       8660 kB
SUnreclaim:        12308 kB
KernelStack:        1128 kB
PageTables:         8736 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      645132 kB
Committed_AS:     833860 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      264612 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359472891 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       42752 kB
DirectMap2M:      219136 kB
```

Comment: Are you using vserver or openvz?

Comment: No, this is a physical rack-mount style server.

Comment: What do initial messages in `dmesg` output say about RAM mapping (how much is "usable")? What does `/proc/meminfo` say?

Comment: Try `cat /proc/cmdline` to see if there's a `mem` limit? (edit: yep, it's `mem=`)

Comment: updating question with better formatted outputs...

Comment: You've got a faulty stick of memory. Run `memtest86+` directly on the server

Answer (score 2):

This ended up as quite a facepalm moment.

I had forgotten to deactivate 'OS Install Mode' in BIOS which limits the RAM to 256MB, among other things I probably did not even notice.